# Convert boost::detail::multi_array::mutable_iterator_tag to std::random_access_iterator_tag

Tags: multidimensional-array, boost, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

I want to use boost boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths algorithm. This code work fine with VS 2010 but when tried to compile with VS 2015 it gives error can not convert from boost::detail::multi_array::mutable_iterator_tag to  std::random_access_iterator_tag

```
        boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths(
        _graph, source,
        boost::make_iterator_property_map(predecessor.begin(), index_map, predecessor[0]),
        boost::make_iterator_property_map(weight.begin(), index_map, weight[0]),
        weight_map, index_map,
        std::less<Weight>(), boost::closed_plus<Weight>(), 
        InfiniteWeight, 0,
        StopWhenTargetReached(target));
```

After some intial analysis found that `boost::make_iterator_property_map(predecessor.begin(), index_map, predecessor[0])`

is giving the error.

How this error can be resolved with VS 2015 ?

Comment: Please not that "predecessor" is a boost multi_array type.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too and through some "magic" changes, I got it working.

See my comment here, https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/4874#comment:43

And please note the disclaimer that says I don't really know what I'm doing here. Hopefully this just leads to someone being able to provide a proper fix to boost.